# Service class inside button isn't working when button is pressed

Tags: android, xml, button, service, onclicklistener

When I press the button send it doesn't start the service for some reason - it was working before , but now it doesn't. The logcat doesn't really give any information as to what is happening. This is very strange considering it was working before. The other button works but this one does not - I am very confused.

```
    Logcat:
    03-15 17:14:33.019: D/OpenGLRenderer(21118): Flushing caches (mode 1)
    03-15 17:14:33.339: D/OpenGLRenderer(21118): Flushing caches (mode 0)
    03-15 17:14:33.339: D/memalloc(21118): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x52622000       size:2088960
    03-15 17:14:33.339: D/memalloc(21118): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x52e21000     size:2088960
    03-15 17:14:33.339: D/memalloc(21118): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5311f000 size:2088960
    03-15 17:14:33.389: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(21118): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
    03-15 17:14:33.389: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(21118): InputConnection = com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@40dabaf0, active client = false
    03-15 17:17:40.369: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(21118): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
    03-15 17:17:40.389: D/memalloc(21118): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x52622000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:60
    03-15 17:17:40.409: D/memalloc(21118): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x52e21000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:64
    03-15 17:17:40.429: D/memalloc(21118): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5311f000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:67
    03-15 17:17:41.981: I/System.out(21118): inside the setServiceAlarm
    03-15 17:17:42.001: D/memalloc(21118): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x52dac000 size:98304 offset:0 fd:70
    03-15 17:17:43.502: I/System.out(21118): inside the setServiceAlarm
    03-15 17:17:45.494: D/memalloc(21118): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x52dac000 size:98304
    03-15 17:17:45.544: D/memalloc(21118): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x52dac000 size:98304 offset:0 fd:70
    03-15 17:17:48.988: D/memalloc(21118): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x52dac000 size:98304
    03-15 17:17:54.174: I/System.out(21118): inside the setServiceAlarm
    03-15 17:17:54.204: D/memalloc(21118): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x52dac000 size:98304 offset:0 fd:70
    03-15 17:17:57.677: D/memalloc(21118): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x52dac000 size:98304
```

The manifest file:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

      <permission 
        android:name="com.example.gmapsapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gmapsapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <uses-permission 
            android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

        <uses-feature 
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.whereyouapp.ControllerTestingScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.whereyouapp.MainScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.whereyouapp.MainSplashScreen" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.whereyouapp.AddRouteScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_route_screen"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.whereyouapp.MainScreen" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.whereyouapp.MainScreen" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.whereyouapp.SavedRoutesScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_credits_screen"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.whereyouapp.MainScreen" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.whereyouapp.MainScreen" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.whereyouapp.TutorialScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tutorial_screen"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.whereyouapp.MainScreen" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.whereyouapp.MainScreen" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.whereyouapp.SettingsScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings_screen"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.whereyouapp.MainScreen" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.whereyouapp.MainScreen" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.whereyouapp.AddRouteScreenMessage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_route_screen_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.whereyouapp.AddRouteScreen" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.whereyouapp.AddRouteScreen" />
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.whereyouapp.SetAddressScreen"
            android:label="Set Address"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.whereyouapp.AddRouteScreen" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.whereyouapp.AddRouteScreen" />
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDxDrvWoRS6mR6FQayfSVQ0oOIz1WOc7mw"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4132500" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The Testing screen:

```
    //This class wil be used to test controller functions, it will consist of a screen with   buttons that do various functions
    package com.example.whereyouapp;

    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
    import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
    import android.telephony.SmsManager;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class ControllerTestingScreen extends Activity{

    public static Context c;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        c=this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_controller_test_screen);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testbutton);
        button.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "inside the onclick", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Controller.setServiceAlarm(getBaseContext(), true);
            }

        };
        button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);

        Button notibutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notificationbutton);
        notibutton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        OnClickListener nbuttonListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());
                mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
                mBuilder.setContentTitle("test");
                mBuilder.setContentText("test2");
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent (getBaseContext(), ControllerTestingScreen.class);
                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getBaseContext());
                stackBuilder.addParentStack(ControllerTestingScreen.class);
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
                mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
            }
        };
        notibutton.setOnClickListener(nbuttonListener);
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
    package com.example.whereyouapp;

    import java.util.Arrays;

    import android.app.AlarmManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.telephony.SmsManager;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Controller extends Service 
    {

    double radius_distance=.8;
    private static final int POLL_INTERVAL = 1000 *3;
    static int number_of_times=0;

    Location currentLocation;
    static LocationManager locationManager;
    double distance;
    // Define a listener that responds to location updates

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() 
    {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
        {
            currentLocation = location;
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };


    public static double coordinatesDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2)
    {
        //returns distance in kilometers between two coordinates
        double deltaLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
        double deltaLong = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
        lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);
        double a = Math.sin(deltaLat / 2) * Math.sin(deltaLat / 2) + Math.sin(deltaLong / 2) * Math.sin(deltaLong / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
        double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
        return 6371 * c; 
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId)
    {
        System.out.println("Working");
       Toast.makeText(this, "inside onStartCommans", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //sendSMS("5613500110","If you received this text message then the Service class for WhereYouApp works");

        if ( locationManager != null )
        {

            // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
            currentLocation  = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER );

        }

        if( currentLocation != null )
        {

            Toast.makeText(this, currentLocation.getLatitude()+"       "+currentLocation.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            distance=coordinatesDistance(currentLocation.getLatitude(),currentLocation.getLongitude(),29.642,-82.344);
            Toast.makeText(this, ""+distance, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println  ( "location not found" );
        }


        if(distance<=radius_distance){

        }

        if(number_of_times==0)
        {
            setServiceAlarm(getBaseContext(),false);
            number_of_times=-1;
        }
        number_of_times++;
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "yolo- the service has stopped working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) 
    {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
        values.put("address", phoneNumber); 
        values.put("body", message); 
        getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
    }

    public static void setServiceAlarm(Context context, boolean isOn)
    {

        System.out.println("inside the setServiceAlarm");
        // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Controller.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (isOn) 
        {
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(), POLL_INTERVAL, pi);
        } 
        else 
        {
            alarmManager.cancel(pi);
            pi.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should register service class in your androidmanifest.xml like,

```
 <service
        android:name="[your service class]"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </service>
```